# Add event in agendaDay view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a problem, when i create an event i works fine, but if i like to create it in agendaDay view, i can't create event. I think that it's for variables, that i need someone, but i don't know which !!!
I search in FullCalendar DOCs but i don't see anything.

Can you help me?? thanks

When i create an event i do this:

```
    NewEvent = {
        id:$('#txtID').val(),
        title:$('#txtTitulo').val(),
        start:$('#txtFecha').val()+" "+$('#txtHora').val(),
        color:$('#txtColor').val(),
        descripcion:$('#txtDescripcion').val(),
        textColor:"#ffffff",
        end:$('#txtFecha').val()+" "+$('#txtHora').val()
    };
```

Problem is that all app works fine what when i click on Add button it doesn't work.

Comment: If you've got a problem with a button please show us the code for the button. Please also show the data you are entering for the event, and also the code where you add it to the calendar. From only the code you've shown we cannot possibly know what the problem is

Comment: I find error, my problem is that i have a SELECT with the hour [08:00,08:30....] and when i use AgendaDay view and i take event, this event have date  and time, and when i like to save this i have 2 hours. Thanks for all!!!